# Background image from file

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link an image to use as a background for a HTML project by using CSS, the image is in a seperate folder, nested in the folder containing the HTML file.

This is my code:

`body {background-image: url(C:\Users\*\Downloads\Website 1\images\background.png); background-size: 100% 100%; }`

I can't get the link to work, so does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Can you share the folder structure of the image vs your HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSS file is in the root folder and images contain on the images folder. You should try like this:

```
body {background-image: url( ./images/background.png); background-size: 100% 100%; }
```